# check if element is under placeholder c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can I know if element is under placeHolder using c# asp.net?

```
PlaceHolder phTest1;
PlaceHolder phTest2;
Label lblTest1;
```

can I know if the label `lblTest1` is in the `phTest1` or under `phTest2` ? by the id of tha label?

Comment: If you could explain why? It might make finding a solution easier (because I do not understand why you need to know that).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "under"? "Lower on the page", "later in the HTML source" (which may not be the same as "lower"), "contained in", or something else?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how you can get parent component.**

```
Control parent = childControl.Parent;
```

Then you can perform whatever check you want with it